# Objective-C: How to retain inputs and also tag names when UItextFields scrolled off?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My App is placing questions and according to the question, placing either UITextField or UISwitch.

When a user input texts it automatically detects which textField and placing the texts accordingly.

It works well but when the items are scrolled off, it removes the user inputs and tag names as well, and when displayes the area placing a new items on top of that.

So when a user input texts it stores it into the old textField.

I would like to know how to prevent it from this issue.

Is there any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"-------------cellForRowAtIndexPath---------------");   

cell_id = [qid objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] ];       
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
label = nil; 
cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self configureLabel];        
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
}

dict = [qtext objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
celltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n",[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
dict = [qtype objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
type = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];     

 //place the question
 cell.textLabel.text = celltext;  

    NSLog(@"celltext=%@",celltext);
    if([type isEqualToString:@"devider"]){      
        [self configureDevider];
    }else{
        [self configureCell];      
    }
    if([cell_id intValue] == ([qid count])){
    tabledone = @"Yes";
    }

tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque=NO;
tableView.backgroundView=nil;

NSString *a = [arrAllheight objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


allheight +=thisheight; 
thisheight =[a intValue];   



if([type isEqualToString:@"YN"]){

    DCRoundSwitch *ynSwitch = [[DCRoundSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,thisheight-40,80,27)] ;  

    ynSwitch.onText=@"Yes";
    ynSwitch.offText=@"No";
    [answers addObject:ynSwitch];
    [cell addSubview:ynSwitch];
    [ynSwitch setTag:[cell_id intValue]]; 
    [ynSwitch addTarget:self  action:@selector(setAnswersForRoundSwitches:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    i++;


}else if([type isEqualToString:@"freetext"]){

    //When the done button was clicked, remove the keybords from the screen
    [self makeTextField];

    [rtxtfield addTarget:self  action:@selector(setAnswersfortextFields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    //    [rtxtfield value]; 



}else if([type isEqualToString:@"dropdown"]){

    picc = [picker_array objectForKey:[[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat:@"%d",cell_id]];

    //Choose an array for this textField
    // [self getPickerArray];
    [self makeTextField];
    //[rtxtfield addTarget:self  action:@selector(setAnswersfortextFields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];  

    //When the done button was clicked, remove the keybords from the screen
    [rtxtfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldReturn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    //Get the tag for picker
    [rtxtfield addTarget:self action:@selector(getTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];     
    //Display picker
    [rtxtfield addTarget:self action:@selector(acsheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];     
    //set Tag for the textField
    [rtxtfield setTag:[cell_id intValue]];
       NSLog(@"rtxtfield tag=%d",rtxtfield.tag);

}


if([type isEqualToString:@"devider"]){   
[self caliculateHeightofCell];
}else{
[self caliculateHeightofCell];
}  


return cell;

}
```

Comment: Yes, i am. I'm sorry I didn't mention it above.

Comment: well the problem might be whit the cell if you use the texfield in the cell i imagin that in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you use something like this     if (cell == nil) { } try doing a little test and comment the //if (cell == nil){  and the colom //} and see if it works

Comment: thanks i tried it but same problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the text to the dataSource. **UITableViewCells must not contain any state information.**

Implement something similar to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 200, 40)];
        textField.tag = 999;
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter text here";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
    textField.text = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    /* configure cell */
    return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIView *contentView = [textField superview];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:textField.text];
}
```

Do not add views outside of `if (cell == nil)`!
If you have different type of cells use a different CellIdentifier! Like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SwitchCellIdentifier = @"SwitchCell";
    static NSString *TextFieldCellIdentifier = @"TextFieldCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (/* current cell is a text field cell */) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TextFieldCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TextFieldCellIdentifier];
            // add textField
        }
        // configure cell...
    }
    else if (/* current cell is a switch cell */) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SwitchCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SwitchCellIdentifier];
            // add switch
        }
        // configure cell...
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for that i will try this and let you know as soon as i get the result...but i need more info about dataSource. i have created a NSMutableArray called 'qtext'. so you mean I can use qtext as dataSource in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Save the state of your controls in your data model *as soon as they change*. So, maybe your model is an array of questions, and each question has an instance variable that can hold the answer. Your view controller is probably both the table data source and table delegate, and you should make it the target of any controls in the cells, too. That is, when you set up a new cell in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, make the view controller the target of the UITextField or UISwitch in the cell. When the user changes either of those controls, then, the change will trigger an action in the view controller, and the view controller can retrieve the new value of the control and store it in the corresponding question in the data model.

If you take this approach, you never have to worry about questions scrolling out of view. As soon as the question scrolls back into view, `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called for that row again, and you'll have all the information you need to reconstitute that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I took a day to fix the problem, but I've finally got it right:
Sorry it's a long code cause it's using textField, DCRoundSwitch, and pickerView.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   NSLog(@"-----------------cellForRowAtIndexPath---------------");       

  Questions *q = [qtext objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSLog(@"question=%@",q.question);
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  static NSString *SwitchCellIdentifier = @"SwitchCell";
  static NSString *TextFieldCellIdentifier = @"TextFieldCell";   
  static NSString *DropDownFieldCellIdentifier = @"DropDownCell";  

  cell = nil;
  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TextFieldCellIdentifier];
  if ([q.question_type isEqualToString:@"freetext"]) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TextFieldCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
    [self makeTextField];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:rtxtfield];            
        cell.textLabel.text = q.question;
        }

    [self makeTextField];
    [self configureCell];
    [self configureLabel];

    cell.textLabel.text = q.question;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rtxtfield];


    rtxtfield.text = [appDelegate.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    rtxtfield.tag=[indexPath row];



}else if([q.question_type isEqualToString:@"YN"]){  
      AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SwitchCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
   [self makeDCRoundSwitch];
   [ynSwitch setTag:[indexPath row]]; 
   cell.textLabel.text = q.question;
    [self configureLabel];
    [self configureCell];
    }
    [self makeDCRoundSwitch];
    [ynSwitch setTag:[indexPath row]]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = q.question;
    [self configureLabel];     
    [self configureCell];

    [ynSwitch addTarget:self  action:@selector(ynSwitchDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    if([[appDelegate.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
        [ynSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }  else{
        [ynSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES]; 
    }

    rtxtfield.tag=[indexPath row];    


   } else if([q.question_type isEqualToString:@"dropdown"]){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:DropDownFieldCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [self makeTextField];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:rtxtfield];            
        cell.textLabel.text = q.question;
    }

    [self makeTextField];
    [self configureCell];
    [self configureLabel];

    cell.textLabel.text = q.question;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rtxtfield];
    picc=q.question_array;

    //When the done button was clicked, remove the keybords from the screen
    [rtxtfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldReturn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    //Get the tag for picker
    [rtxtfield addTarget:self action:@selector(getTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];     
    //Display picker
    [rtxtfield addTarget:self action:@selector(acsheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];     
    //set Tag for the textField
    [rtxtfield setTag:[indexPath row]];      



   //  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    rtxtfield.text = [appDelegate.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    rtxtfield.tag=[indexPath row];

}


 [self makeTextField];
 rtxtfield.tag=[indexPath row];

tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque=NO;
tableView.backgroundView=nil;


return cell;

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

label = nil;

```
//cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self configureLabel];        
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
//}
```

comment your code like that and tell me what happens

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it but doesn't work. the same problem remains and white rectangle background appears on each question. I set background as clear.

Comment: I think the problem is when the view is loaded, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called twice and place questions and items twice.

Comment: the cellforrowatindexpath needs to be called for the exact number of rows your table has

Comment: my app has only 4 questions, but initially the method is called 8 times.

Comment: disabling cell reuse is not the answer

Comment: @MatthiasBauch it was just to test see where the problem is

Comment: bad style, bad performance. It's just not how it should be done. You are introducing bad code to cover a bug. It works though...